# How would I animate a BlurEffect to any control?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, effects

I would like a reusable function that simply does a BlurEffect on any particular valid Control type.

e.g.

```
var animation = new DoubleAnimation
{ 
   From = 0,
   To = 8,
   Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 2),
   AutoReverse = true
};
control.Effect = new BlurEffect();
// How to cycle the From and To on the Blur Radius?
```

I am uncertain how to dynamically create an animation in code behind to make this possible.

Comment: am i right in assuming that you dont want the xaml to be aware of the blur at all?

Comment: I do not wish to do this in the XAML if that's what you mean.

Comment: but you dont want to define the blureffect in xaml either right?

Comment: I wouldn't mind it as a resource if that is what you are asking.  I would be triggering this in code behind however no matter what.

Comment: I have updated my code sample to show everything except what I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2006102701.aspx) shows how to define an animation and story board in code.

You'd need to add the BlurEffect and use [RadiusProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.blureffect.radiusproperty.aspx) of blureffect instead of RotateTransform.AngleProperty like this:

```
control.Effect.BeginAnimation(Blureffect.RadiusProperty, animation);
```

-edit-

I see now that you're using Silverlight, not wpf (where [Effect implements IAnimatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.effect.aspx))
i'll try and find a solution for silverlight

-edit2-

Have you seen/tried [this](http://blogs.veracitysolutions.com/how-to-build-a-storyboard-animation-in-c-sharp/)? Msdn also has a [sample for silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard%28VS.95%29.aspx)

-edit3-

Your direction got me towards the right answer which is as follows:

```
private void BlurSomething(FrameworkElement control)
        {
            var storyboard = new Storyboard();
            var animation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = 0,
                To = 8,
                Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                AutoReverse = true
            };
            var effect = new BlurEffect();
            control.Effect = effect;
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            Storyboard.SetTarget(storyboard, control.Effect);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(storyboard, new PropertyPath("Radius"));
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
```

It should be noted that Silverlight does not make animations as easy as WPF, but in the end this can be done.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but it doesn't cover off how to do a DoubleAnimation against the Radius on a BlurEffect.

Comment: you'd do it the same way as in the article, just switch out RotateTransform.AngleProperty to BlurEffect.RadiusProperty

Comment: Sorry, there is no way to just switch these out because BlurEffect does not have a BeginAnimation.

Comment: aah... you're using silverlight, not wpf.. sorry

Comment: I'm getting real close.  Will update your response with the final solution.